# Docker nginx minitet

Tags: docker, mininet

I'm trying to run mininet hosts as docker containers instead. I can start them with a ubuntu images, but when I try to start with a nginx image, it fails starting the nginx service. I suspect that this happens because mininet will only create the network after the hosts are created.

Anyone knows a way around to this problem?

Where's my nginx image:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get install -y net-tools inotify-tools nginx apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD service nginx start
```

I also tried `CMD sleep 5 && service nginx start &`, but it doesnt seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`service nginx start` is non blocking

You need to add `daemon off;` in the nginx conf and launch it without using service